# why doesnt service method rollback when doing integration testing?

Tags: grails, integration-testing, grails-2.2

I want to include only relevant code.

```
void testSaveQuestion_WrongRaceId(){
    ...
controller.savequestion(raceGroup.id)
    ...
}
```

The save question controller uses service method which is transactional by default. The call to service method is shown below.

```
  def savequestion(Long id){


            try {

                surveyService.saveQuestion(id, params, question, event)

            }
            catch (ValidationException e) {
}

    }
```

If i set

```
static transactional = false
```

then it works. i.e if an exception is thrown in service method then it rollsback.

but if i comment out

```
//static transactional = false
```

then it fails. i.e if an exception is thrown in service method then it doesnt roll back.

I check this rolling back behavior by asserting the entries in the database. For example if there is an exception then a question is not supposed to be saved in database but if there is not an exception then the count of question is 1.

So i am wondering why is service method not rolling back after an exception is thrown when doing integration testing? Why does it work only after making transactional = false in integration testing class. Please note i am using grails 2.2

I appreciate any help!

Comment: try with static transactional = true instead of comment out

Comment: commenting out static transactional = false means transactional = true. Integration tests are by default transactional. I tried your suggestion and no effect.